# Facing Issue while creating Custom User Store Manager [WSO2 API Manager 1.9.1]

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am totally new to WSO2. I have to create custom user store manger using wso2 api manager. While some word around I am facing an exception as,

TID: [0] [AM] [2016-01-14 16:19:57,732]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AgentHolder} -  Agent created !    {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AgentHolder}
TID: [0] [AM] [2016-01-14 16:19:57,736]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.AgentDS} -  Successfully deployed Agent Client {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.AgentDS}
TID: [0] [AM] [2016-01-14 16:19:59,608] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService} -  Cannot initialize the realm. {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService}
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: org.wso2.sample.user.store.manager.CustomUserStoreManagerType class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

I have updated user-mgt.xml as,

```
 <UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.sample.user.store.manager.CustomUserStoreManager">
        <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager</Property>
    <Property name="ReadOnly">false</Property>
        <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
        <Property name="IsEmailUserName">false</Property>
        <Property name="DomainCalculation">default</Property>
        <Property name="PasswordDigest">SHA-256</Property>
        <Property name="StoreSaltedPassword">true</Property>
        <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
    <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameUniqueAcrossTenants">false</Property>
        <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">^[^~!#$;%^*+={}\\|\\\\&lt;&gt;,\'\"]{3,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">^[^~!#$;%^*+={}\\|\\\\&lt;&gt;,\'\"]{3,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
        <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
    <Property name="SharedGroupEnabled">false</Property>
        <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
    </UserStoreManager>
```

I have also registered service as,

Public class CustomUserStoreMgtDSComponent{

```
 private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CustomUserStoreMgtDSComponent.class);
 private static RealmService realmService;

    protected void activate(ComponentContext ctxt) {
        log.info("Custome Component activated..");
        CustomUserStoreManager customUserStoreManager = new CustomUserStoreManager();
        ctxt.getBundleContext().registerService(UserStoreManager.class.getName(), customUserStoreManager, null);
        log.info("CustomUserStoreManager bundle activated successfully..");
    }

    protected void deactivate(ComponentContext ctxt) {
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Custom User Store Manager is deactivated ");
        }
    }

    protected void setRealmService(RealmService rlmService) {
          realmService = rlmService;
    }

    protected void unsetRealmService(RealmService realmService) {
        realmService = null;
    }
```

}

I have also added sample-store.jar inside dropins folder.

Is there any reference guide/link to create custom user store manager through wso2 api manager?

Any help would be highly appreciable.